# my conditional returns undefined instead of true/false

Tags: angularjs, return, conditional-statements

I'm using angularjs and trying to set up a flag on the front end for my ng-if. I wanted to consolidate the logic in the controller but the the ng-if is only returning true and never false.

I need some efficient way for my code to return false if conditions are not met instead of returning undefined.

```
vm.showLocButton = !vm.isSupervisorReviewApp && vm.application.benefitPeriod.program.programType.id === vm.constants.programTypeId.directBill && vm.application.applicationStatus.code === vm.constants.applicationStatus.locIssued;
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont know exactly but I see '=' instead of '==' are you assigninv the value or comparing if comparing than try using '=='

vm.showLocButton == !vm.isSupervisorReviewApp && vm.application.benefitPeriod.program.programType.id === vm.constants.programTypeId.directBill && vm.application.applicationStatus.code === vm.constants.applicationStatus.locIssued;

It will really helpful if you  can post the entire code.